# Estimate geo-coordinates based on tweets using sparse coding

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to estimate Geo-coordinates of tweets on Twitter based only on characteristics of tweets' content. I used an algorithm from [this](http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/ICWSM/ICWSM15/paper/viewFile/10561/10482) paper.

Basically, the tweets from users are collected and pre-processed to create a sequence/word-count vectors. Sub-vectors (patches) are extracted and an unsupervised learning method is used for learning Dictionary ([KSVD](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~elad/publications/journals/2004/32_KSVD_IEEE_TSP.pdf)). Using the learned Dictionary, sparse codes can be found. After that, a max pooling scheme is introduced. Finally, a look-up table is created with entries of key (sparse code)/value (Geo-coordinates). For estimating Geo-coordinates of tweets (same user), we calculate corresponding sparse codes, then use kNN to find the neighbors. The geo-coordinates can be estimated by the average value of these neighbor vectors.

Following is how I implement the algorithm:

- I extracted data from [GeoText](http://www.ark.cs.cmu.edu/GeoText/) dataset, separating data by user (say,80% of users for the training set, and 20% for the validation set)
- Patches/sub-vectors are put together to create a big matrices of the training set and the validation set
- For learning dictionary, I used KSVD-BOX from: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~ronrubin/software.html
- For sparse coding, I used OMP-BOX from the same aforementioned website
- Some necessary parameters:

  - N = 64 (dimension of patch or sub-vector)
  - K = 600 (number of atoms)
  - T = 10 (sparsity)
  - kNN = 30 (number of the nearest neighbours)
  - epsilon = 0.1 (whitening constant)

It can be seen that the algorithm runs pretty fast, taking 10 minutes for training, and 5 minutes for testing. However, I've never obtained a high accuracy. In fact, the mean value distance errors is always around 1000 km, which is not as good as in the paper (500km). I've followed every points in the paper, including enhancement options. Here is my [Matlab source code](https://github.com/lenhhoxung86/tweetgeolocation).

Well, I know the description is pretty long, but I tried to explain what I understand in an easy way. I hope you can help me improve the accuracy.
Thank for your patient.